# Why does my simple batch script quit unexpectedly after line 59?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I made this batch file to execute certain commands for my kit for web dev, however, the bat file quits after line 59. Why is it quitting?

I noticed, however, that if I remove line 59 from the file and run it. It works fine. The only thing is, I have to physically type that line in after the bat file finishes.

You can try to reproduce the problem by downloading my [kit](https://github.com/NicholasAdamou/StarterKits/archive/master.zip) from my GitHub and extracting the contents of the zip to a location that you prefer.

Just navigate to the `Gulp/Starter Kit` directory and run the setup.bat file.

**Batch File:**

```
@echo off
TITLE Starter Kit
runas /noprofile /user:Administrator cmd
goto :checkNodeVersion

:checkNodeVersion
  cls
  echo Current NodeJS version:
  call npm -v
  timeout 5
  if errorlevel 1 goto :installNode
  goto :updateNode

:installNode
  cls
  echo Installing NodeJS:
  powershell -Command "(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://nodejs.org/dist/v5.3.0/node-v5.3.0-x64.msi', 'node-v5.3.0-x64.msi')"
  echo downloading file, node-v5.3.0-x64.msi, from https://nodejs.org/dist/v5.3.0/node-v5.3.0-x64.msi....
  set "fileName=node-v5.3.0-x64.msi"
  %fileName%

  echo NodeJS was successfully installed.
  timeout 5
  goto :updateNode

:updateNode
  cls
  echo Updating NodeJS:
  call npm cache clean -f
  call npm install -g n
  call n stable

  cls
  echo NodeJS was successfully updated to version #:
  node -v
  timeout 5
  goto :installBower

:installBower
  cls
  echo Installing Bower:
  call npm install -g gulp bower

  echo Bower was successfully installed.
  goto :installGulp

:installGulp
  cls
  echo Installing GulpJS:
  call npm install -g gulp

  echo GulpJS was successfully installed.
  timeout 5
  goto :installDependencies

:installDependencies
  cls
  echo Installing Project Dependencies:
  call npm install && bower install
  ::Quits unexpectedly after line 59
  call npm install --save-dev gulp-rucksack
  call npm install --save-dev gulp-imagemin
  call npm install --save imagemin-pngquant

  echo Project Dependencies were successfully installed.
  timeout 5
  goto :primaryFunction

:primaryFunction
  cls
  echo Starter Kit Log:
  echo NodeJS is installed.
  echo GulpJS is installed.
  echo Gulp Dependencies are installed.
  set /p response="Would you like to continue? <y/n>"

  if /i "%response%"=="y" (
    cls
    set "filePath=%~dp0"
    cd %filePath%

    gulp help
    cmd /k
  )

  if /i "%response%"=="n" goto :exitFunction

:exitFunction
  cls
  echo Starter Kit is Closing
  exit
```

Comment: What's `npm` you are `call`ing? another batch file?

Comment: @aschipfl its `Node Package Manager` npm

Comment: What is bower and what does it do?

Comment: @Squashman http://bower.io/ - A command line utility or package manager. Visit the site for more info.

Comment: @NicholasAdamou I am referring to this line of code: call npm install && bower installs. Is bower a batch file?

Comment: @Squashman No, it's not a batch file.

Comment: `call` is intended to run another batch file and return to the main script afterwards; for your external applications (`npm`, `bower`), try to run them directly (no `call`), or use the `start` command: `start "" /WAIT "command arguments"...

Comment: @aschipfl the thing is, though, I run the program w/o the call command and once it reaches the line `npm -v`, the batch file quits without continuing and I don't know why.

Comment: Hmm... that's not line # 59... I'd try `npm` (and also other external tool) isolated, with and without `call` and `start "" /WAIT` to see if that is really causing the problem...

Comment: @aschipfl Yeah, I realize that. I've been proactive and I know how the `start` command works. I just want the program not to terminate after that `npm -v` call. It's odd that when  I leave the `npm -v` there and run, it quits right after and doesn't get to the `timeout 5`. When I put the `call npm -v` the cmd window doesn't close, it gets to the `timeout 5`. It's odd, b/c I shouldn't have to use `call` with what I am trying to do.

Comment: One last idea is to use `cmd /C npm -v`...

Comment: that makes sense to use that b/c `cmd /k` will just exec the command and remain while `cmd /c` will terminate after the command was exec. That fixed the `call` problem, however, where it says, `cmd /c npm install && bower install` it quits. I would believe it's not the syntax that causes the program to quit. something about the `npm` is probably causing it.

Comment: My research suggests that `npm` really does invoke a batch file.  Try `where npm` at the command line to double-check.

Comment: Known issue https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2938

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the following quote from https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/bower.html, bower is a batch script (.cmd file).

> In this field, specify the location of the Bower executable file
>   (**bower.cmd** or other depending on the operating system used).

So you need to change line 59 to read as follows:

```
  call npm install && call bower install
```

Without CALL, you never return from bower.

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks for your answer! It makes a ton more sense now!

Comment: @NicholasAdamou weird how it became a batch file 6 hours later.

Comment: @Squashman I wasn't aware that it was before now. So good to know.

Comment: @NicholasAdamou did you bother to look at the extension of the file?

Comment: @Squashman with bower? No, it's just a package manager that works through the command prompt so it makes sense that it is .bat  file. I should have been more proactive and looked that up. I was just thinking it had to do with something bigger and not just bower. In any case, good to know.

Comment: @NicholasAdamou Occam's Razor.